# Converting sympy Jacobian back to numpy

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have a list of "n" sympy functions of which the Jacobian is calculated for the list of symbols "jlist":

```
from sympy import symbols, zeros

jlist = symbols('sj0:%d'%n)
Fa = zeros(n,1)
Fa[0] = jlist[0]+jlist[2]
Fa[1] = 2*jlist[1]
...
Fa[-1] = 3*jlist[-1]

JFa = Fa.jacobian(jlist)
```

The Jacobian will be sparse and since some of the functions are nonlinear, it will contain symbols. Now I would like to convert Fa and JFa into numpy arrays. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: but numpy arrays are best if they contain numbers, not symbols or sympy expressions.  There are lots of SO about the problems of using sympy and numpy together.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do or why. Why do you want to convert them into numpy arrays? Do you mean that you want to substitute values for the symbols and then have a numpy array with concrete numbers as the result?

Comment: Sorry for if my question wasn't clear. The derivation of the Jacobian is done once. The substitutions of the sympy symbols with numbers has to be carried out thousands of times. Instead of having to each time substitute a sympy symbol with a number (which is very slow), I'd rather convert the sympy expressions into "numpy expressions", e.g. numpy arrays which contain references to numpy arrays (that contain the values of the symbols).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have noted, parts of this seem like an odd question, but assuming I understand what you are saying, it is possible to do what you ask.  Keep in mind that numpy doesn't have any knowledge of 'symbols' or anything in sympy; what you really need is some function or callback that takes in numeric values of your jlist and evaluates a numpy array with all of the expressions evaluated.  Using the subs function in sympy would indeed be too slow.

The lambdify feature of sympy does exactly what you need.

```
from sympy import symbols, zeros, lambdify, Eq, MatrixSymbol, Matrix
from IPython.display import display
n = 5 # was undefined, I just picked 5
jlist = symbols('sj0:%d'%n)

Fa = zeros(n,1)
Fa[0] = jlist[0]+jlist[2]
Fa[1] = 2*jlist[1]
Fa[-1] = 3*jlist[-1]
JFa = Fa.jacobian(jlist)

jlistValues = [1,2,3,4,5] 
display(jlist)

faEvaluationFunction = lambdify(jlist, Fa)
faEvaluated = faEvaluationFunction(*jlistValues)
display(Eq(MatrixSymbol('f_a', n, 1), Fa)) # being fancy by displaying the full equation
display(Eq(MatrixSymbol('f_a', n, 1), Matrix(faEvaluated)))

# showing an alternate way to pass the arguments in (note passing in the list in a list and the lack of a * when evaluating)
jacobianEvaluationFunction = lambdify([jlist], JFa)
jacobianMatrix = jacobianEvaluationFunction(jlistValues)
display(Eq(MatrixSymbol('J_{f_{a}}', n, n),JFa))
display(Eq(MatrixSymbol('J_{f_{a}}', n, n),Matrix(jacobianMatrix)))
```

For the particular function you listed, the matrix returned contains only constants, however you said that in it might contain symbols so that needs to be evaluate'able with numbers at some point.  I am not sure if the array returned is a numpy array, but numpy's array should be able to parse this.

If this isn't what you were going for, let me know and we can iterate on what you need.

BTW, thank you for showing me the jacobian function on sympy's Matrix!  I've been doing that by hand all this time.

Comment: My gratitude is great (sorry for the vague formulation). This works exactly as intended.